# Spring Webflux Wait for a Flux inside a Flux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-mongodb

Here is the scenario, i Have a Flux that comes from a ReactiveMongoDB and another from WebClient, soo
i need that for each item in Mongodb, I look for his items in a webclient.

The problem is that, i have been using block to wait from the webclient itens to come and this is affecting the performance.

If i not use Block, the response is send without the itens from webClient, soo its probaly not waiting this itens do come.

Is there any way to make all calls and wait later from this itens?

```
 return planetaRepository.findAll().flatMap(planetaVO -> {
                planetaServiceFacade.recuperarFilmesParticipados(planetaVO.getNome()).collectList().doOnNext(planetaVO::setFilmes).block();
                return Flux.just(planetaVO);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this instead, by using `thenReturn`

```
return planetaRepository.findAll().flatMap(planetaVO -> {
    return planetaServiceFacade.recuperarFilmesParticipados(planetaVO.getNome()).collectList()
                        .doOnNext(planetaVO::setFilmes)
                        .thenReturn(planetaVO);
});
```

And i suggest you dont write code in your native language, if you are not forced to.

Comment: even better: use `map` to load the `List` into the `planetaVO`, returning it in one go (instead of `doOnNext`+`thenReturn`)